# php server ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost, server

I can't make a php server run on my local computer. I tryed with wampserver and Easy PHP. I checked the usage of my `port:80`, I changed the port from `:80` to `:8080`, I gave Apache and mysql the permissions required on the firewall settings... I did everything, but when a type `http://localhost` with or without the port number browser answer is always the same:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can you help me, please?

Comment: We are going to need some more information.   What operating system and what version?  Since you state "wampserver", it is the Windows OS.     Another point of clarification .. PHP is not a web server, so you need to ensure you either have a PHP based webserver, or a webserver (like IIS, etc..)

Comment: I think your down votes are because this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: guys sorry by the off-topic, but it was my first (and desperate) question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @jewettg, The OS is Windows seven x64. About the PHP based webserver. Was said to me that Wampserver or EasyPHP is everthing I need to localy run wordpress on my PC. Is this the truth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think this questions is off-topic, I will try to answer it.

I have had problems with Skype and WAMP running at the same time. If you have Skype open, close it and WAMP, then open just WAMP. There is a setting in skype to use an alternate port. It has been covered thousands of times all over the internet.

Close everything you can think of.. Zone Alarm or any other software based firewall, disable Windows firewall, temporarily disable your AV if it has a built in firewall. I am not saying you *should* run without protection, but you need to identify what is causing the troubles. As far as hardware firewalls, I have a Linksys wireless router (built in firewall) and I have never had to do anything to get WAMP to work behind it.

If you have been messing with tons of settings in your WAMP, then just uninstall it and re-install it. You don't need to change your port to 8080 to get it working, and doing so would require you to always include :8080 in your URL (unless you have it listen on both).

With a stock WAMP, and everything you can think of closed or disabled, try again.

The WAMP icon should be green. Click on it, and go into both Apache and MySQL. They have a "services" sub-menu, where you can start/stop/restart the service. Start should be greyed out, and stop and restart should be available. If you see one of them not started, try clicking "start service". If it still won't start, then click "Install Service". Wait a minute. Then click "Start Service".

For some reason, when I freshly install WAMP, I have to manually install the service on one of them. I don't recall which one. Once I install the service, it then will work. You might have to click the WAMP icon again, and select "Restart All Services". Then go into the Apache and MySQL menus and make sure the services are started.

Comment: @KallewRodriguesGuedes Glad you got it working, please accept my answer.

Comment: I backed up my files, uninstalled WampServer, downloaded a new copy of WampServer, installed this, copied my files back, and created a new database and db user and imported my SQL, and the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` remains. It never went away originally when I disabled Windows Firewall and Glasswire Firewall and AVG Anti Virus. The site has been put online, and port 80 is in use by Apache's WampServer. Stumped.

Comment: Turning Windows Firewall, Glasswire, and AVG all off does not change things after reinstalling WampServer. :(

Comment: Aha. I forgot the live production site was on `https` and did not notice my local site was loading on `https`. I switched to `http` and the error went away. :)

Comment: Like Steve, `https` was the issue for me too....check .htaccess for an HTTP->HTTPS rewrite rule

Answer (score 0):

OK after about an hour of trying all of the fixes and youtubes I could find, I read Wade's approach. So with that knowledge I went:
`wamp menu->apache->services->start/resume` and boom localhost wamp page popped right up.

This was a fresh install the error for `localhost` was `404 err connection refused`.

I hope this helps your frustration.