# Getting 404 not found error while assigning php file as source even though my php file is there

Tags: php, web, server

I have created an iframe in HTML like:

```
<p class="input-block">
    <iframe src="php/image.php" height="50" width="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="captcha-frame" name="captcha_image_frame"></iframe>
</p>
```

this html file is located under `inetpub/wwwroot/Site`, and there is a image.php file under `inetpub/wwwroot/Site/php`. However, when I enter the html page, I see the error on console:

> GET http://demo.com/php/image.php 404 (Not Found)

If I chance src to "`http://localhost/php/image.php`", then I get the error:

> GET http://localhost/php/image.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Note: When I enter `http://demo.com/php/image.php`, I get not found error as well, but I expect not to get it since there is a image.php under php folder:(

The question is, how can I manage to assign image.php to the iframe source. I appreciate if anyone helps.

Thanks!

*demo is not the original domain.

Edit:
image.php content:

```
<?php

session_start();
header("(anti-spam-content-type:) image/png");

$enc_num = rand(0, 9999);
$key_num = rand(0, 16);
$hash_string = substr(md5($enc_num), $key_num, 5);
$hash_md5 = md5($hash_string);

$_SESSION['verify'] = $hash_md5;
// Verification Image Background Selection

$bgs = array('1.png');
$background = array_rand($bgs, 1);

// Verification Image Variables

$img_handle = imagecreatefrompng($bgs[$background]);
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 255, 255, 255);
$font_size = 5;

$size_array = getimagesize($bgs[$background]);
$img_w = $size_array[0];
$img_h = $size_array[1];

$horiz = round(($img_w / 2) - ((strlen($hash_string) * imagefontwidth(5)) / 2), 1);
$vert = round(($img_h / 2) - (imagefontheight($font_size) / 2));

// Make the Verification Image

imagestring($img_handle, $font_size, $horiz, $vert, $hash_string, $text_colour);
imagepng($img_handle);

// Destroy the Image to keep Server Space

imagedestroy($img_handle);
```

Comment: Server machine is using Windows 8

Comment: Do you want to show captcha?? @Eray

Comment: Why this much long way to show a captcha. Show your image.php file contents for better understanding.

Comment: Allright, I added @Subin

Comment: unfortunately, still getting the same errors:(

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because port 80 is using by some other application. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448399/php-server-err-connection-refused) will help you. If Skype running, change Skype settings and reinstall server.

So to show a captcha, I do this way, by converting image to data URL.in html instead of iframe, directly use img tag

```
<img src="./php/image.php" />
```

in php as follows

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatefrompng("./1.png"); 
imagepng($im, NULL, 0);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: @Eray Replace your image.php with this contents.

Comment: @Eray error 404 is because some other application using your port 80

Comment: unfortunately still getting the same errors. I dont think it is related to image.php content since even it is empty or includes such code we are sure it is working normally, same error keeps to be gotten. Somehow, it seems like the file is not located on the server, even though it is located in wwwRoot.